# How to use auto complete with from JSON data Swift

Tags: swift, swift3, autocomplete

How do I use my JSON data to become a auto complete in Text field.

so I have a Json look like this

```
[
  {
    "city_name": "City1",
    "province": "province1"
  },
  {
    "city_name": "City2",
    "province": "province2"
  },
  {
    "city_name": "City3",
    "province": "province3"
  },
  {
    "city_name": "City4",
    "province": "province4"
  } 
  { //etc }
]
```

this value already been saved to a Model. So If I have to get the value of this json I just need to call a model. 
However I don't know how to implement to a textfield, when the textfield is tap there will be a auto complete from this json.

> example : when I type in the textfield "C" it will show " City1, City2, and etc "

Thank you

**EDIT**

I need this to be programmatically.

I already have a code for my textField

```
//View
let fillCity: BaseTextField = {
        let fillCity = BaseTextField()
        fillCity.textColor = UIColor().greenColors()
        return fillCity
    }()
```

BaseTextField is the same with UITextField just a little custom for underlined

In ViewController

```
//ViewController
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupViews()

    }
private func setupViews(){

    mainView = view as! MerchantInformationView
//other code
}
```

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: only autocomplete 3party i found. i don't want to use that thats why

Comment: @StevenTan check updated answer..

Comment: hey, 
Have you found the answer? @StevenTan

Answer (score 0):

After you have made the logic for the textField OnChange event, you can filter the strings in the array with this:

```
resultsArray = wholeArray.filter({ (textEntered) -> Bool in
     let tmp: NSString = text as NSString
     let range = tmp.range(of: stringWithoutSpaces, options: NSString.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive)
     return range.location != NSNotFound
})
```

textEntered - The text being write on the textField

resultsArray - The array with the filtered data

wholeArray - The array with the whole data to be filtered

And then added to a tableView or whatever you are using to show the filtered data